# image noise reduction in android

Tags: android, image-processing

I've written a camera app which allow users to capture image of paper bills, send to server where it'll be printed.

Problem:
when I print the image, the background is blackish due to noise in captured image. All I want is a clean white background. I've tried Bitmap's compress method to save the image in JPEG/PNG format on different scales (1-100) but not much helpful. I've seen camscanner app doing this fantastically but have no clue how.

Any pointer to achieve this will be helpful.

thanks.

Comment: When you say the background is blackish, do you mean there is some salt/pepper noise? or that it is a dark gray? can you elaborate?

Comment: @Noremac its darkgray. Images will be plain text (black) on a white paper. But white background isn't white enough for printers - print comes with dark gray background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the issue is some random noise, there are some noise removing filters out there you can use (i.e. median filter or a bilateral filter).

Is the image already binarized (converted to strictly black and white pixels)? You'd want to do the filtering before this.

EDIT(after clarification on dark gray): Since the background is a dark gray I'm guessing the problem is just that it is a low contrast and since it will be a natural image, there will be variation on how bad the contrast is. I suggest using Sauvola binarization for this which will separate out the black and the dark gray to black and white. Here is some detail and example results of Sauvola: http://www.leptonica.com/binarization.html. To run some tests to see which binarization algorithm would be best you can find a library [here](http://liris.cnrs.fr/christian.wolf/software/binarize/index.html)

Comment: thanks @Noremac. Though it hasn't solved the issue completely but clues are vital. I can work on it further.

Comment: @iuq,i you get any solution then please share ,how to remove noise of imge

Answer (score 0):

Changing compress ratio cannot give any help to this question. A strong filter will help you reduce the noise.
Try to have a look at this [Link](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/)